# How to fix the error of printing values using vector and iterators

Tags: c++

A Set S and Q queries are Given. Initially, S is empty. In each query:

positive integer X is inputed into S.
For each y ∈(belongs to) S before this query such that y≠X, you should also insert y⊕X into S (⊕ denotes the XOR operation).
The set cannot have duplicate elements, so if you try to insert into S an element that is already present in S, then nothing happens.

I Check Whether the set,i.e,Vector in this case(as I need to store Values in order) is empty and insert x,else,I use an Iterator to find the value of x in the vector and run a loop from the beginning till the end and check the XOR of the elements in the loop with x,and if not present,insert it into the vector.

The Code gives the correct answers for most of the part but sometimes gives some garbage value.

```
        cin>>x;
        if(v.empty()){
            v.push_back(x);
        }else{
            verify = check_set(x,v);
            if(verify == false){
               v.push_back(x);
              it2 = find(v.begin(),v.end(),x);
                for(it=v.begin();it!=it2;it++){
                    temp = (*it)^x;
                    verify = check_set(temp,v);
                    if(verify == false){
                    v.push_back(temp);
                    check = check_x(temp);
                    }
```

Expected Output - 4 2 6 7 3 5 1

Actual Output - 4 2 6 7 3 13046527 1

Answer (score 0):

Your code is breaking one of the rules of vector iterators. With a vector, any iterators to the vector are *invalidated* if an element is added to the vector. So in this code

```
it2 = find(v.begin(),v.end(),x);
for(it=v.begin();it!=it2;it++) {
    temp = (*it)^x;
    verify = check_set(temp,v);
    if(verify == false){
       v.push_back(temp); // it and it2 are invalidated here
       ...
```

you are invalidating your iterators and you should not use them any more. This won't always cause problems which is why you get correct results *most* of the time. But potentially any time you add something to a vector you invalidate all the iterators that refer to that vector.

The simplest way to fix this problem is to use indexes instead of iterators.

Another way would be to `reserve` sufficient space in your vector before you add anything to it. This only works if you know in advance how big your vector is going to get.

Another way would be to use a set instead of a vector. Iterator invalidation can still happen with sets, but the rules are much less restrictive than with vectors.